# Anychart not accepting variable

Tags: java, android-studio, mpandroidchart, mobile-application, anychart

I am playing with charts in Android Studio. In the tutorial, the number 41, 56 and 93 is being put directly into the ValueDataEntry like so and it is working.

```
data.add(new ValueDataEntry("BUB", 41));
data.add(new ValueDataEntry("KP", 56));
data.add(new ValueDataEntry("SP", 93));
```

But when I try to make user input number to the ValueDataEntry, it is not working. So I try to set the input directly to the below code but it is still not working. I tried to change the integer to float and also double but it is still not working. I suspected the parameter of ValueDataEntry is something I'm not familiar with because double, integer and float are not working but it is accepting numbers like the code above. Help me to insert values into the pie chart through variables. Help is very much appreciated.

```
private void makeChart() {
        ArrayList<DataEntry> data= new ArrayList<>();
        int test=41;
        int test2=56;
        int test3=93;
        data.add(new ValueDataEntry("BUB", test));
        data.add(new ValueDataEntry("KP", test2));
        data.add(new ValueDataEntry("SP", test3));
        Pie pie = AnyChart.pie();
        pie.data(data);
        anyChart.setChart(pie);
    }
```

p/s I also had try using the other chart library called MPAndroidChart and it has a problem very much like this. If only I can know what parameters are taken by ValueDataEntry. By the way, in Android Studio, the code snippet above is not throwing error so I don't know why it is not showing the pie.

Comment: after update data in mpchart, chart.invalidate should be invoked to make the data update to take effect, please have a try

Comment: @CookChen it is working thank you very much. Why I dont know this method exist

Comment: It's not a mpchart method, invalidate will incur draw and the the data can be drawn